# How to plot errorbars in ggplot2 R for geographical/locational centroids?

Tags: r, ggplot2, gis, latitude-longitude, centroid

I'm encountering an issue with the `geom_errorbar` argument where I receive the error `Error: geom_errorbar requires the following missing aesthetics: x or y, xmin and xmax`.

I have several datasets and would like to use them all to create a single geographical ggplot. Below is a workflow and some example data. The desired plot will have background location data in `dat`, the centroids in `centroids` and *x* and *y* errorbars/standard deviation ranges for for the centroids which are calculated in the `centroids` dataframe (i.e., "Longitude_weighted_sd" and "Latitude_weighted_sd".

```
#packages
packages<-c('tidyverse','sf','rgdal','rnaturalearth','ggspatial','raster','sp', 'cowplot',
            'dplyr','ggplot2','lubridate','stargazer', 'purrr', 'geosphere', 'purrr')

lapply(packages, library, character.only = T)
library(ggplot2)
library(sf)
library(rnaturalearth)
library(rgdal)
library(ggspatial)
library(spData)
library(cowplot)
library(tidyverse)

#download geographical and upload personal/mock data 
world <- ne_countries(scale = "medium", returnclass = "sf")
states <- map_data("state")
data("us_states", package = "spData")

dat <- data.frame(Latitude = c(35.8, 35.85, 36.7, 35.2, 36.1, 35.859, 36.0, 37.0, 35.1, 35.2),
                  Longitude = c(-89.4, -89.5, -89.4, -89.8, -90, -89.63, -89.7, -89, -88.9, -89),
                  Period = c("early", "early", "early", "early", "early", "late", "late", "late", "late", "late"),
                  State = c("A", "A", "A", "T", "T", "T", "T", "A", "A", "A"))

#function to calculate weighted variance, sd, and se
weighted.var <- function(x, w = NULL, na.rm = FALSE) {
  if (na.rm) {
    na <- is.na(x) | is.na(w)
    x <- x[!na]
    w <- w[!na]
  }
  
  sum(w * (x - weighted.mean(x, w)) ^ 2) / (sum(w) - 1)
}
weighted.sd <- function(x, w, na.rm = TRUE) sqrt(weighted.var(x, w, na.rm = TRUE))
weighted.se <- function(x, w, na.rm = TRUE) sqrt(weighted.var(x, w, na.rm = TRUE))/sqrt(length(x))

#calculate centroids for "early" and "late" periods weighted by "State" observations
centroids <- dat %>% 
  group_by(Period, State) %>% 
  mutate(weight = 1/n()) %>%
  group_by(Period) %>%
  summarise(across(starts_with("L"), 
                   list(weighted_mean = ~ weighted.mean(.x, w = weight),
                        weighted_sd = ~ weighted.sd(.x, w = weight),
                        weighted_se = ~ weighted.se(.x, w = weight))))
```

If I take out the `geom_errorbar` argument everything works great. However when I add it in I receive the error that `geom_error requires the following missing aesthetics:x or y, xmin and xmax` however, I thought that I've specified everything. Below is the ggplot2 code. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
plot1 <- ggplot(data = world) +
  geom_sf(fill = "gray92") +                                                          #light gray
  geom_polygon(data = states, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group),                  #states outline
               color = "black", fill = NA) + 
  geom_point(data = dat, aes(x = Longitude, y = Latitude, color = Period),            #background data 
             alpha = 0.2, size = 1) +
  geom_point(data = centroids, aes(x = Longitude_weighted_mean, y = Latitude_weighted_mean, 
                                       fill = period), size = 6, pch = 21) +          #centroids
  geom_errorbar(data = centroids,
    aes(ymin = Latitude_weighted_mean - Latitude_weighted_sd,                    
        ymax = Latitude_weighted_mean + Latitude_weighted_sd,
        xmin = Longitude_weighted_mean + Longitude_weighted_sd,
        xmax = Longitude_weighted_mean + Longitude_weighted_sd),                      #errorbars
      ) +
  theme_bw() + 
  coord_sf(crs = "+proj=aea +lat_1=29.5 +lat_2=45.5 +lat_0=37.5 +lon_0=-96 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs") +
  coord_sf(xlim = c(-92, -88), ylim = c(33.5, 36.7), expand = TRUE) +    
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 20),
        legend.title = element_text(size = 20),                       
        legend.text = element_text(size = 16),
        axis.title = element_text(size = 20),
        axis.text = element_text(size = 16),
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1),
        element_line(color = "black"))+
  annotate("text", label = "TN", size = 7, x = -88.3, y = 35.3) +
  annotate("text", label = "AR", size = 7, x = -91.7, y = 36) +
  annotate("text", label = "MS", size = 7, x = -89, y = 34) +
  xlab("Longitude") + ylab("Latitude")

plot1
```

Thank you in advance for anyone willing to assist. -nm

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. I have added quotations around Period and State observations to make reproducible.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you try two add the error bars via one `geom_errorbar` and as the error message is telling you you neither provided `x` nor `y`. Instead I would suggest to add your error bars via two `geom_errorbar`s like so:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(rnaturalearth)
library(tidyverse)

ggplot(data = world) +
  geom_sf(fill = "gray92") + # light gray
  geom_polygon(
    data = states, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group), # states outline
    color = "black", fill = NA
  ) +
  geom_point(
    data = dat, aes(x = Longitude, y = Latitude, color = Period), # background data
    alpha = 0.2, size = 1
  ) +
  geom_point(data = centroids, aes(
    x = Longitude_weighted_mean, y = Latitude_weighted_mean,
    fill = Period
  ), size = 6, pch = 21) + # centroids
  geom_errorbar(
    data = centroids,
    aes(
      x = Longitude_weighted_mean,
      ymin = Latitude_weighted_mean - Latitude_weighted_sd,
      ymax = Latitude_weighted_mean + Latitude_weighted_sd
    )
  ) +
  geom_errorbar(
    data = centroids,
    aes(
      y = Latitude_weighted_mean,
      xmin = Longitude_weighted_mean - Longitude_weighted_sd,
      xmax = Longitude_weighted_mean + Longitude_weighted_sd
    )
  ) +
  theme_bw() +
  coord_sf(xlim = c(-92, -88), ylim = c(33.5, 36.7), expand = TRUE) +
  theme(
    plot.title = element_text(size = 20),
    legend.title = element_text(size = 20),
    legend.text = element_text(size = 16),
    axis.title = element_text(size = 20),
    axis.text = element_text(size = 16),
    axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1),
    element_line(color = "black")
  ) +
  annotate("text", label = "TN", size = 7, x = -88.3, y = 35.3) +
  annotate("text", label = "AR", size = 7, x = -91.7, y = 36) +
  annotate("text", label = "MS", size = 7, x = -89, y = 34) +
  xlab("Longitude") +
  ylab("Latitude")
```

[image]